# AVQueuePlayer with SWRevealViewController in iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I am using SWRevealViewController for left side menu in my application.I am using objcetive c. 5 menu option in SWRevealViewController. I am using AVQueuePlayer in home menu(first view).

My problem is when I am clicking another option in menu bar and navigating on another view at that time AVQueuePlayer stop playing it self. How can I fix this?

Note: AVQueuePlayer is Properly working while application is in background with home menu.

```
 NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
 NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];

// Change the default output audio route
UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof(doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);

NSArray *queue = @[
                   [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:chanel_url_str]],
                   ];

self.player1 = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:queue];
self.player1.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance;

[self.player1 addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"currentItem"
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                  context:nil];

void (^observerBlock)(CMTime time) = ^(CMTime time) {
    NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.2f", (float)time.value / (float)time.timescale];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {

    } else {
        NSLog(@"App is backgrounded. Time is: %@", timeString);
    }
};

self.timeObserver = [self.player1 addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(10, 1000)
                                                               queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()
                                                          usingBlock:observerBlock];

[self.player1 play];
```

Here chanel_url_str is NSString with URL format.